# Create grouped boxplot with R boxplot()

Tags: r, boxplot

I have four data frames each representing different tissues. Their structure is the following:
As column(name)s I have a set of different genes and as row(name)s different samples, each value is the amount of that certain gene in that sample.

```
gene1 <- c(1,3,5,3,2,1)
gene2 <- c(2,4,6,4,2,4)
gene3 <- c(4,2,5,3,2,4)
gene4 <- c(3,5,3,2,4,5)

df <- rbind(gene1, gene2, gene3, gene4)
colnames(df) <- c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample5", "sample6")

df
       sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6
gene1    1       3       5       3       2       1
gene2    2       4       6       4       2       4
gene3    4       2       5       3       2       4
gene4    3       5       3       2       4       5
```

(I have "df" four times, each having the same rows, but different samples in the columns coming from four different tissues)

I would now like to group the four tissues so they are plotted together for each Gene.
So the boxplot should look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1HnV.png
(sorry, I'm not yet allowed to post the picture)
, with A and B being genes and their amount on the y-axis.

Any idea on how to achieve this? I am aware of the value function but couldn't figure out how to use it to achieve my goals.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshape large dataset with multiple columns from wide to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120697/reshape-large-dataset-with-multiple-columns-from-wide-to-long)

Comment: Reshape and then plot with `boxplot(A~B) `